# Is it possible to deploy a juju service to multiple specific machines?

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

i am trying to deploy HA ceph like shown in [OpenstackHA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA) But i wanted to deploy Ceph MON and Ceph OSD on same 3 machines. So in order to that, my 1st cmd will be,

```
juju deploy --config local.yaml -n 3 local:ceph
```

and 2nd cmd, i am wondering how i should do, coz i want to deploy CEPH-OSD to same machines.
something like this,

```
juju deploy --force-machine 0 --config ceph.yaml local:ceph-osd
juju deploy --force-machine 1 --config ceph.yaml local:ceph-osd
juju deploy --force-machine 2 --config ceph.yaml local:ceph-osd
```

or can it be like this,

```
juju deploy --force-machine 0,1,2 --config ceph.yaml -n 3 local:ceph-osd
```

I have not tried these command actually and not good aware of cmd syntax also, thats why i am asking it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ juju add-unit -h
usage: juju add-unit [options] <service name>
purpose: add a service unit

options:
-e, --environment (= "local")
    juju environment to operate in
-n, --num-units  (= 1)
    number of service units to add
--to (= "")
    the machine or container to deploy the unit in, bypasses constraints

Service units can be added to a specific machine using the --to argument.
Examples:
 juju add-unit mysql --to 23       (Add unit to machine 23)
 juju add-unit mysql --to 24/lxc/3 (Add unit to lxc container 3 on host machine 24)
 juju add-unit mysql --to lxc:25   (Add unit to a new lxc container on host machine 25)
```

Comment: "juju add-unit ceph-osd --to 1" will be after 1st cmd "juju deploy --force-machine 0 --config ceph.yaml local:ceph-osd"  ?

Because i don't see in add-unit cmd syntax that we can specify ceph.yaml?

Comment: yes, its deploy for config and 1 unit, and then add-unit twice for the additional ones.

Answer (score 1):

From a Juju developer:

> We discussed it, but I think we ended on `--to` and `-n` together is an
>   error. We might support something like `--to ec2:us-east-1b -n5` in the
>   future. But for now, you have to deploy and then `add-unit --to 2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that the ceph charm is a superset of the ceph-osd charm; i.e. the ceph charm provides MON's and OSD's.  If you just want three machines, just use the ceph charm.

See [Installing ceph and ceph-osd charms on same machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343349/installing-ceph-and-ceph-osd-charms-on-same-machine) for more details.