# Installing ceph and ceph-osd charms on same machine?

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

I have 3 ceph nodes, I have decided to install ceph monitor plus ceph osd on all 3 servers. In order to do that I deployed 1st ceph charm on all 3 nodes. Till here everything was fine, I was even able to see ceph health status as "OK".

Then I installed ceph-osd to 1st unit (which is already deployed with ceph charm) and then added 2 more units(which were already deployed with the ceph charm) to the ceph-osd service.

And then I did `juju add-relation ceph ceph-osd`, I am getting following result,

```
ceph:
    charm: local:precise/ceph-92
    exposed: false
    relations:
      mon:
      - ceph
      osd:
      - ceph-osd
    units:
      ceph/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "relation-joined"'
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "1"
        public-address: cs1.master
      ceph/1:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "relation-joined"'
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "2"
        public-address: cs2.master
      ceph/2:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "relation-joined"'
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "3"
        public-address: cs3.master
  ceph-osd:
    charm: local:precise/ceph-osd-7
    exposed: false
    relations:
      mon:
      - ceph
    units:
      ceph-osd/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "1"
        public-address: cs1.master
      ceph-osd/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "2"
        public-address: cs2.master
      ceph-osd/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.12.0
        machine: "3"
        public-address: cs3.master

'hook failed: "relation-joined"' How can i resolve this error?
```

Also now ceph status is giving error,

```
cs1:~$ sudo ceph statusunable to find any monitors in conf. please specify monitors via -m monaddr or -c ceph.conf

2013-09-09 09:13:06.723165 7fed6793c780 -1 ceph_tool_common_init failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ceph charm provides a superset of the functionality of the ceph-osd charm; if you just want to try out a small three node deployment, just use ceph - it will configure MON daemons by default and can also use attached storage for OSD (Object Storage Daemon) as well:

```
juju deploy -n 3 ceph
```

A larger ceph deployment would consist of three service units of the ceph charm and then N service units of the ceph-osd charm;  the ceph-osd service units just run the OSD's for storage capacity

```
juju deploy -n 3 ceph
juju deploy -n 1000 ceph-osd
juju add-relation ceph ceph-osd
```

Deploying both charms on the same physical/logical servers won't work; the configuration files will conflict and trounce each other resulting in a non-functional deployment.